# Calculate GameObject Damage based on distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a number that `x%` between a minimum and a maximum number.

So for example if I have the following:

```
min = 5;
max = 10;

// `c` is a Collider type
float distance = Vector3.Distance(c.transform.position, transform.position);
float percent = distance / radius;
```

So now what I am looking for, is when `object B` is closer to the edge of `object A`'s radius for my final number to be closer to `5`. When `object B` is closer to the center of `object A`, I would like the final number to be closer to `10`.

I have the above so far, but I am not sure what the final formula is to get an `Object Damage Amount`. Basically think of this a proximity mine, the farther you are away the less damage you will take and the closer you are the more damage you will take.

Comment: This seems like a math question. You need to decide how it scales with distance. Does it scale linearly? Exponentially? Something else?

Comment: Right now I am using Linear.. But It would I like the idea of having other methods as well..

Comment: float result = damage * 1 / Mathf.Sqr(distance); this one is based on the physics equation for gravity. The closer you get, the bigger the result. Bbut instead of being linear, it makes a curve so that as you get closer the increase in the result gets faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = (1.0f - percent) * (max - min) + min;
```

just make sure that distance is always <= radius (i.e. percent >= 0.0 and percent <= 1.0)